# How can I keep multiple gevent servers serving forever?

Tags: python, blocking, gevent

Currently, I have an application that has two servers: the first processes orders and responds individually, the second broadcasts results to other interested subscribers.  They need to be served from different ports.  I can start() both of them, but I can only get one or the other to serve_forever() as I read it is a blocking function.  I am looking for ideas on how to keep both the servers from exiting.  abbreviated code below:

```
def main():
    stacklist = []
    subslist = []
    stacklist.append(CreateStack('stuff'))
    subslist.append(Subscription('stuff'))
    bcastserver = BroadcastServer(subslist) # creates a new server
    tradeserver = TradeServer(stacklist) # creates a new server
    bcastserver.start() # start accepting new connections
    tradeserver.start() # start accepting new connections
    #bcastserver.serve_forever()  #if I do it here, the first one...
    #tradeserver.serve_forever()  #blocks the second one

class TradeServer(StreamServer):
    def __init__(self, stacklist):
        self.stacklist = stacklist
        StreamServer.__init__(self, ('localhost', 12345), self.handle)
        #self.serve_forever()  #If I put it here in both, neither works

    def handle(self, socket, address):
        #handler here

class BroadcastServer(StreamServer):
    def __init__(self, subslist):
        StreamServer.__init__(self, ('localhost', 8000), self.handle)
        self.subslist = subslist
        #self.serve_forever()  #If I put it here in both, neither works

    def handle(self, socket, address):
        #handler here
```

Perhaps I just need a way to keep the two from exiting, but I'm not sure how.  In the end, I want both servers to listen forever for incoming connections and handle them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ok, I was able to do this using threading and with gevent's monkeypatch library:

```
from gevent import monkey
def main():
    monkey.patch_thread()
# etc, etc
t = threading.Thread(target=bcastserver.serve_forever)
t.setDaemon(True)
t.start()
tradeserver.serve_forever()
```

Answer (score 2):

I know this question has an accepted answer, but there is a better one. I'm adding it for people like me who find this post later.

As described on in the [gevent documentation about servers](http://www.gevent.org/servers.html):

> The BaseServer.serve_forever() method calls BaseServer.start() and then waits until interrupted or until the server is stopped.

So you can just do:

```
def main():
    stacklist = []
    subslist = []
    stacklist.append(CreateStack('stuff'))
    subslist.append(Subscription('stuff'))
    bcastserver = BroadcastServer(subslist) # creates a new server
    tradeserver = TradeServer(stacklist) # creates a new server
    bcastserver.start() # starts accepting bcast connections and returns
    tradeserver.serve_forever() # starts accepting trade connections and blocks until tradeserver stops
    bcastserver.stop() # stops also the bcast server
```

The gevent [introduction documentation](http://www.gevent.org/intro.html#event-loop) explains why this works:

> Unlike other network libraries, though in a similar fashion as
>   eventlet, gevent starts the event loop implicitly in a dedicated
>   greenlet. There’s no reactor that you must call a run() or dispatch()
>   function on. When a function from gevent’s API wants to block, it
>   obtains the gevent.hub.Hub instance — a special greenlet that runs the
>   event loop — and switches to it (it is said that the greenlet yielded
>   control to the Hub).

When serve_forever() blocks, it does not prevent either server from continuing communication.

Note: In the above code the trader server is the one that decides when the whole application stops. If you want the broadcast server to decide this, you should swap them in the `start()` and `serve_forever()` calls.

Answer (score 0):

Start each server loop in its own instance of Python (one console per gevent). I've never understood trying to run multiple servers from one program. You can run the same server many times and use a reverse proxy like nginx to load balance and route accordingly.

Comment: the two servers need to share the same internal state

Comment: now we need to ask ourselves if that's a good design decision.

Comment: yes, i agree it isn't ideal.  the design requires a broadcast server to publish a subscription based summary of activity over one port, and handle interaction via a different API on another port.  I think a database solution wont be fast enough: 000's of messages per second mean polling can't be used.  I'd like to eventually daemonize both processes, so if they can be independently started and stopped.  This would require some sort of transport link between them.  For now, it just works, and running them from the same process helps me develop and test other functionality more quickly.

Comment: rewrote it as separate processes with a socket transport layer. Unfortunately, that took the messages/sec performance down by a factor of 10, but the setup could be useful if the separation is needed, and the performance requirements were lower. Still, I'm glad I explored it, thank you for your input.

Comment: how are you passing data back and forth exactly? raw connections or with a library?

Comment: pretty much raw sockets, but wrapped in json.  messages are < "twitter sized".  On my test rig, I am processor bound, but it's because I am running my message generator and the listeners all on the same machine.  Thoughts?  I appreciate your advice.

Comment: I should clarify: the threaded version is processor bound, the separated version gets IO bound around 0.1x the message speed, but at least gevent deconflicts them nicely :)

Comment: how many cores are on your local machine? and what operating system are you using? If I were you, I'd use a simple Celery server with a redis or memcached backend to push your messages onto a queue in RAM that get picked up by the second server. Keep in mind though, each python instance is using "1 core" so you'll want at least a dual core to run your two servers; you can run Celery in the same instance that you're pushing messages into it from. Also, the queues are bi-directional if you need to send a message back to the original server. :)

Comment: developing on an iMac with 4 cores, but plan to deploy in linux - at least 4 should be available in production.  I have looked into a bit, but it will take some more time to wrap my brain around it and select the right architecture.  It certainly should eliminate the IO lag that I experienced using sockets. I wont do it right now, but I am selecting your answer in thanks!

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/36415/discussion-between-domoarrigato-and-blake-vandemerwe)